# Approximate the CDF of the sum of 2 probability distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given two complicated CDFs $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ on random variables $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Is there a way to approximate for the combined CDF $h(x)$ on $X + Y$ without having to perform a convolution on the distributions, given their complicated nature?

Comment: Not without further information

Comment: Plz also provide the distributions of $X$ and $Y$. The general approach I think you know but want to avoid using it; the reason why can only be seen if you provide the distributions

Comment: Note also that the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$ are not sufficient to answer the question; you also need the _joint_ CDF of $X$ and $Y$ (unless of course you are told that $X$ and $Y$ are independent in which case the joint CDF is just the product of the marginal CDFs.